# Changing URL with Routing, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am still very new to routing with asp.net mvc, so perhaps this is obvious and I am just missing the answer...

I have a controller named 'pages', and it has several action results, 'Information', 'History' etc. Each action result takes a string, and from that, it returns a View based on the name of the string. So...

Pages/Information/About
Pages/Information/Products
Pages/History/Employees

etc. The Controller is named 'Pages', of course. I'm wondering if I can use Routing to remove the 'Pages' part of the URL on the user side, just for a more user-friendly approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep you can do that:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Pages_History_Employees",
            "History/Employees", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Pages", action = "History" }
        );
```

Just specify the controller as Pages and specify whatever url you want as the second parameter. What this is saying is I want to route the History/Employees URI to the Pages controller and use the History action to handle this route.

Just be careful that if you have the default MVC route in there that it appears at the end of your routes or it will match this route first. Then you will get an error since it will be looking for the History controller with the Employees action.